# FireBase slow loading

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I want setting app by firebase analytics. This app is working but, init loading is slow as 13~15 second. However different app is faster than my app. How can fix my app?

**D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.**

Perhaps, I think that this part's problems.
Please help me that.

Comment: Can you paste some of your codes so others can understand more about your situation?

Comment: This question is ambiguous. There is not enough information in my opinion.